# Is there a way to get React App folder with all components from build folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to make some changes on my website, but I didn't find any code, so I have only static files on my hosting. Is there a way to get my code back from chunks or do I have to write all from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely there is no way to retrieve the source code from the obfuscated code.